# How to update (put/post request) related fields with Django rest api?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django. Within the Django rest framework, I'm struggling with the put & post request on a table that's linked to other table(s).

The main table I want to update via API is `person`, that's basically where contact details are kept. It joins to 2 other tables, `email`, `phone`, where each of them only contains 1 piece of information (as their name stated). What I'm trying to achieve is that when I submit a put/post request to `person`'s api, it also updates `email`, `phone` without needing to update each of them respectively.

Below are some code:

Models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.ManyToManyField('Email')
    phone = models.ManyToManyField('Phone')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['last_name', 'first_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'

class Phone(models.Model):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.phone}'

class Email(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.email}'
```

Serializers:

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    phone = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('id', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'email', 'phone')

class PhoneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Phone
        fields = ('id', 'phone')

class EmailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Email
        fields = ('id', 'email')
```

Views:

```
class PersonViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer

class PhoneViewSet(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Phone.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PhoneSerializer

class EmailViewSet(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Email.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EmailSerializer
```

In the `person` API detailed view, under put request, `email` and `phone` fields are currently grayed out and says "No items to select", I'm hoping to be able to enter values in there, and can successfully submit the put/post request via the front end (React) of my app.

[image]

I've been stucking here for weeks, any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: You need to override the **`update`** method of the serializer. Ref this for more info [**Writable nested serializers**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be able to answer my own question now, also in case someone else is having the same issue. This is how I resolved it.

As @JPG mentioned, you can also override the `update` and/or `create` method to define how to handle related fields explicitly, but there is a way easier approach.

```
from drf_writable_nested import WritableNestedModelSerializer

class PersonSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):
    last_name = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=100)
    first_name = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=100)
    address = AddressSerializer(many=True)
    email = EmailSerializer(many=True)
    phone = PhoneSerializer(many=True)


    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('id', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'address', 'email', 'phone', 'group')
```